# Apache server not able to download file having copy as file name

Tags: apache, browser

In a web application user has provision to upload a files to the server which can be downloaded and viewed in future. We have to maintain the file name same as that it was uploaded for future downloads.

When a user uploads a file name having **copy** as a file name like **Copy_template.xls** the Apache server throws 403 error, but if we rename the file by removing copy they are able to download. How to fix this?

Comment: Myself got the same problem.